# Git status for the current working directory

Tags: plugin-fugitive

As you know `:G` generally applies for the git directory of the current file.

How do you make it work for the current working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I defined `:GCWD` for current working folder.

```
function! GitDir()
let top = systemlist("git rev-parse --show-toplevel")[0]
return top . "/.git"
endfunction


function! GCWDComplete(A, L, P) abort
return fugitive#Complete(a:A, a:L, a:P, {'git_dir': GitDir()})
endfunction

command! -bang -nargs=? -range=-1 -complete=customlist,GCWDComplete GCWD exe fugitive#Command(<line1>, <count>, +"<range>", <bang>0, "<mods>", <q-args>,   { 'git_dir': GitDir() })
```

based mainly on others code (https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/1981 ), so made it a wiki.